# Reading iPhone's call log over Bluetooth (using PBAP), some entries are omitted

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm trying to read an iPhone's call log over Bluetooth. I've tried not only with my own code (using PBAP), but also with [BlueFTP application for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-file-transfer-blueftp/9nblggh627zb).

On the phone itself, the Phone app's call log groups together several calls that were executed to/from the same number, one right after the other, showing them as just one entry in the call log. Then, if the user clicks on such entry, they would see a list with the exact times of all the calls to or from that caller.
See screenshots below for example:

[image: call log]
[image: call log entry details]

Seems like the same grouping logic applies also when querying for the phone's call log - with one major difference: the data which I get over Bluetooth has no indication about those grouped calls. Instead, for each of the grouped calls, I'll see only the latest timestamp, without any indication about how many (if at all) other timestamps were grouped together into it.

I'm suspecting this is a bug in iOS, but perhaps there could be some workaround? Or maybe some parameter in the Bluetooth connection or the request itself, which might affect this result?